# How to return table data as different format types via views in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have below view which returns data of three different models Employees,Testimonial and Skills and it is perfectly working.

**Views.py**

```
@page_template("app/profession.html") # just add this decorator
def profile(request, template="app/profession.html",
extra_context=None):
context = {
    'employ_V': Employees.objects.get(id = 45),
    'testim_V':Testimonial.objects.get(id = 45),
    'skills_V':Skills.objects.filter(id = 45),
}
if extra_context is not None:
    context.update(extra_context)
return render_to_response(template, context,
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

If you see, there is only one record that will be returned for Employees and Testimonial models (*Notice* objects.get() in the query)
whereas Skills model has more than 1 record (it returns id,skill,order fields for more than 5 rows).

Is it possible to use same view to return Skills as Json format along with Employee and Testimonial to my template (plain text and JSON) ?
Or should I use separate view to return data in Json format for Skills model ?
What could be the best approach in this case.

In a separate view for Skills - I could achieve the results successfully in JSON format - for this I used customer serializer and JsonResponse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Django `values` from queryset, but if you need special transformation (like thumbnail for image or so on) add to your model `as_dict` method

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    # here your fields

    def as_dict(self):
        context = {
            'pk': self.id,
            'name': self.name,
            # ...
        }

        return context
```

Then in your views

```
# import section 
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
# ...


@page_template("app/profession.html") # just add this decorator
def profile(request, template="app/profession.html", extra_context=None):

    employ_v_obj = Employees.objects.get(id=45)
    testim_v_obj = Testimonial.objects.get(id=45)
    skills_v_qs = Skills.objects.filter(id=45)

    skills_v_json_list = [obj.as_dict() for obj in skills_v_qs]

    context = {
        'employ_V': employ_v_obj,
        'testim_V': testim_v_obj,
    }

    context['skills_V_json'] = mark_safe(json.dumps(skills_v_json_list, ensure_ascii=False))

    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)

    return render_to_response(template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand.. My question is different, you might want to have a look into it once again..  I wanted to return only Skills as json data format leaving Employee and Testimonial plain text format to the template

Comment: "I wanted to return only Skills as json data format leaving Employee and Testimonial plain text format" so I've demonstrated how you can combine it in one context data

Comment: Hi madzohan, Is it possible to return plain text data as well as Json data formats as output via view in DJango 1.8 as per the code I put in my question?  I can return Skills as dictionary, but cannot do as Json along with Employee and Testimonial being plain text.

Comment: Thanks a lot for updating your answer.. I will give a try and keep you informed.

Comment: Hi madzohan, Thank you so much!, it helped me to return the data in json along with plain text in the context.

Comment: Hi Madzohan, could you pls have a look at my other question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085439/render-to-response-or-redirect-changes-the-template-elements-in-django-1-8